# In win32 C++ programming to close a window, should I call DestroyWindow(hWnd) myself or SendMessage(WM_CLOSE, hWnd, 0, 0)?

Tags: winapi

I'm handling `ESC` key in my application and when this key is received I wish to close the current window.

Should I simply call `DestroyWindow(hWnd)` or should I `SendMessage(WM_CLOSE, hWnd, 0, 0)`, or should I be closing the current window in some different way?

Comment: If all your `WM_CLOSE` handler does is call `DestroyWindow()` then there's no reason not to just call it directly. Depends on if you want to do any other processing (e.g. show a "Are you sure you want to quit?" dialog).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I don't do any other processing, my `WM_CLOSE` handler simply calls `DestroyWindow()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)`. It puts the `WM_CLOSE` message into the window's message queue for processing, and the window can close properly as the message queue is cleared.

You should use [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The difference is that `PostMessage` simply puts the message into the message queue and returns; `SendMessage` waits for a response from the window, and you don't need to do that in the case of `WM_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you which you use. Should the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key act just like clicking the close button, or should it definitely destroy the window?

The default implementation of [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as found in [`DefWindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) calls [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so if you're not handling [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically then one is as good as another. But [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't necessarily have to call [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though, so if the window in question handles it then it could do something else. For example, [it could pop up a "Are you sure?"-type message box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#destroying_win), or simply do nothing. [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will bypass all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Either `PostMessage` or `SendMessage` `WM_CLOSE`

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm trying that. PS. What's the difference between PostMessage and SendMessage?

Comment: Been a long time since I did Win32 -- from memory, SendMessage sends the message synchronously whereas PostMessage works asynchronously by putting the message on the queue for normal message processing.

Comment: -1 While you suggest the `PostMessage` is as good as `SendMessage`, `SendMessage` is certainly the wrong tool.